# Scala Jackson object mapper setting null instead of default values in case class

Tags: json, scala, jackson, mapper

have a case class Person with default param.

pass mapper a string missing a param, mapper sets it as null.

expecting it to set the default value

why is this ?

example :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
case class Person(id:Int,name:String="")

class MapperTest extends SpecificationWithJUnit {

  "Mapper" should {

     "use default param" in {

        val personWithNoNameString = """{"id":1}"""

        val mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
        val personWithNoName = mapper.readValue(personWithNoNameString,classOf[Person])

        personWithNoName.name must be("")
     }
  }
}
```

get error :

```
'null' is not the same as ''
java.lang.Exception: 'null' is not the same as ''
```

Answer (score 2):

Jackson mapper is using reflection to set the properties and disregards default values in the case class constructor. 
There is an open [ticket](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/issues/87), and it seems that the suggested solution in the comments does not work

```
case class Person(id:Int,name:String=""){
     def this() = this(0,"")
}
```

Comment: will not compile (expected Int got null)

Comment: updated the response, null.asInstanceOf[Int] is 0, otherwise use an Option[Int]

Answer (score 1):

Works with @JsonCreator annotation:

```
case class Person(id:Int,name:String = ""){
     @JsonCreator
     def this() = this(0,"")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above worked for me, but I thought it was less than ideal to define defaults twice. There is another way which also works, avoiding the need for duplicate default declarations.

```
case class Person(id:Int, name: String = "")

object Person {
  @JsonCreator
  def default = Person(0)
}
```